# Nginx rewrite rule not works when using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using nginx, and is configured to proxy_pass the requests

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
```

So when user asks for

```
https://example.com/salon/1234
```

every thing works fine.

Now I need this URL to works either

```
https://example.com/salon/1234/anystringt
```

So I wrote this

```
rewrite ^(.*)/salon/([0-9].*)/(.+)$ /salon/$2 last;
```

and it does hot work.

When I change the rewrite rule to

```
rewrite ^(.*)/salon/([0-9].*)/(.+)$ /salon/$2 redirect;
```

everything works fine but it redirecting the user.
Any one knows why the first rewrite rule does not work?

Comment: Qq do you NOT want to send `/1234` to your upstream server? So your client request `/salon/1234/anything` will be sent as `/salon/anything` to your upstream server? Regardless of the regex the request URI will be passed through to the upstream server. Please share the whole `location` configuration including the `location /xyz {` line

Comment: $2 is 1234. the location is /